# Regex expression to check whether two folder paths are same

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query, regex-lookarounds

In mongodb documents, we have a key which has values like this:

```
a/b
a/b/c
b/c/d
```

Two paths are same, if both are equal or one path contains the other. For example:

`a/b`, `a/b` - are same

`a/b`, `a/b/c` -  same as first one contains other

`a/b`, `a/c` - different. Even though parent is same, they have different children path

`a/b`, `a/bc` - different

`a/b`, `/a/b/` - same

Now, while inserting a new document, I have to check whether that path is unique. I have to generate regex dynamically to check that. Is this possible to do this using regex expression?

Suppose `a/b/c` is already stored in db. The new document contains `a/b`, I can write regex something like `^/{0,10}a/{1,10}b/{0,10}`. But if db contains `a/b` and the new document contains `a/b/c/d`, how to write regex for `a/b/c/d` so that it matches `a/b`

Comment: Doesn't "a/b" and "a/b/c"  violate the constraint ?

Comment: Both are same as a/b contains the path a/b/c. The problem is whatever I write in `a/b` folder can overwrite a/b/c

Comment: contains or is prefix/suffix? what about b/c and a/b/c/d? contains in the sense of a tree structure or a string?

Comment: It's a prefix. b/c and a/b/c/d would be invalid. Imagine a folder structure /a and folder a/b. There is a folder a in first case. In the second case there is a folder b inside folder a. That's what I meant by 'contain'. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

[Now you have two problems](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/) =)

Although if you consider non-regexp solution, you can benefit from [$indexOfCP operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfCP/). If I get your question (assuming a typo in the "code" snippet) you want to check if either of 2 strings starts from or equal to the other. In mongo terms:

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $or: [
      {
        $eq: [
          0,
          {
            $indexOfCP: [
              "$fieldname",
              theString
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        $eq: [
          0,
          {
            $indexOfCP: [
              theString,
              "$fieldname"
            ]
          }
        ]
      },

    ]
  }
})
```

where `fieldname` is the name of your key property, and `theString` is the string you are testing.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Actually, it is not as simple as substring problem. `a/b`, `a/bc` are not same. Regex is painful but I wanted to go with that as `a///b` can match `a/b`. That is another part of the problem

Comment: I would go with normalisation of the paths - add a trailing slash and remove consecutive slashes. Anyway my point still stands - if you want to use regexp and can find a shorter string in a longer one, add an $or clause with the same regexp and reversed arguments.

Comment: Yeah, that's helpful. Wouldn't it be expensive? But I guess it's better than nothing.

Comment: The direct regexp you already have `^/{0,10}a/{1,10}b/{0,10}` can actually be much faster - it is anchored to the beginning of the string and can benefit from an index. $indexOfCP cannot. But the reverse search is completely different matter - it costs the same for $indexOfCP but building a new regex for each document will be dead slow. As I said - consider normalisation. You do it once per document on insert/update and it will save you billions on CPU ticks at query time.